# What's the correct way of doing API requests in React for components that update?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, api, request

I have two components: App and Movie. In my App component I show a list of movie ID's (they come from my local database), and in the Movie component I show a detailed view of the Movie ID that has been clicked.

Inside the Movie component I fetch some data from the IMDB API for the matching ID. The movie ID gets passed to the Movie as a prop.

No Movie component is shown by default. If a Movie ID is clicked, the Movie component is shown. Once it is shown, another Movie ID can be clicked from the list and the Movie component must be updated with the newly fetched data from the API.

What is the correct way of doing the API requests? If I do it in componentDidMount(), then an API request will only happen the first time the Movie component renders. If I do it in componentWillReceiveProps(), then the Movie component only does the request if it got updated after it has rendered. Is it okay to just use both componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps? Or is there a more appropriate way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using componentWillMount which will be fired before the component has mounted.
[Here](https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-react-lifecycle-methods-ddc79699b34e) is a good guide regarding component lifecycle.